# Aligning Multiple Data Sets that have different time intervals or data gaps

Tags: r, excel, statistics

I have several sets of data in csv files from a variety of years. Some of the data overlaps nicely, but others have years without data, or “gaps”, some have different time intervals between data points, and most of them have different ranges of years in which the data was collected. Is there a relatively simple way of organizing these different sets of data, either in R or in Excel, to match all the data up with the years aligning? I would prefer not to do this manually with large sets of data and I am sure there must be a way to do this reasonably.

Currently each set of data is its own csv file. It might be the most simple to combine them into one Excel, but as I said, I would prefer not to do that by hand if possible. Simply copy-pasting it in would have the years not align properly either, so I need some way to have it take the value of the years into consideration.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What form would you want your "aligned" data to take? How many columns are there in each data set? Are years recorded separately from month/day or in a single date column?

Comment: A simple set of columns, probably either in a csv file or Excel document. Having the first column with the year and subsequent columns with the data entries correlating to that year seems like it would be the most organized way for my data. Each data set is two columns, one with the year and the other with the data entries themselves. Month and day are not included.

Comment: So is there one row per year in each csv file, with gaps? A lot of years?

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity. Maybe an example would be most helpful. So for a hypothetical two data sets:
Data set 1:
Year:         Entry:
1980          15
1985          24
1990          22

Data set 2:
Year:        Entry:
1980         15
1981          11
1982          12
1983          9
etc

Comment: That came out a bit of a mess, sorry. I guess comments don't allow formatting. For data sets that have yearly data, there are yearly rows. Data sets that only have one data point every 5 years will only have one row per 5 years. So there is only a row when a data point is actually available.

Comment: As you note, it's hard to read the info in the comments. Can you edit that info into your original post, and format there?  Thanks!

Comment: You can create a stand-alone df as year_df which has all the year and you can just left_join other csv files into this year_df. If you can provide specific examples maybe we can help with the code.

Comment: My advice is, don't try to align the data. A fixed time resolution is a bed of Procrustes -- don't force your data to fit your analysis, but rather, adjust your analysis to conform to the data you have.

Answer (score 0):

Using `plyr`

```
library(plyr)

d1 <- data.frame(year=1980:2010, a = rep(1,31))
d2 <- data.frame(year=1990:2010, b = rep(1,21))
d3 <- data.frame(year=c(1980:1990, 2000:2010), c = rep(1,22))   

join_all(list(d1, d2, d3))
```

or if you want to use `dplyr`

```
library(tidyverse)

d1 %>% 
  left_join(d2) %>% 
  left_join(d3)
```

Comment: B Williams - how do you determine that should be doing a left join? I have a similar problem as the poster - I've got 5 variables and 5 other columns that record their timestamps and wondering how to merge them all together

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses Excel in-cell formulas only. Provided the all data is manageable in a single spreadsheet (not too many CSV files, not too many rows per file), then I suggest

1. You load each csv into a separate tab of a single spreadsheet, say CSV1, CSV2, CSV3 etc.
2. In a another tab, say ALIGN, in col A put a list of every year, spanning the range of years in all the files with no gaps
3. In Col B of ALIGN use =IFNA(MATCH($A12, 'CSV1'!$A:$A, 0),"") to find the CSV1 row in which the year in Col A matches ALIGN year (example for ALIGN row 12)
4. In Col C do the same for CSV2, etc.
5. Now you have lists, in each columns B, C, D etc., of which rows in each CSV tab CSV1, CSV2, etc match which date
6. In another tab, say OUTPUT, use formulas like =IFERROR(INDEX('CSV1'!C:C, 'ALIGN'!$B132), "") to get the corresponding data from col C of CSV1 (again example for OUTPUT row 32).

In the OUTPUT tab you can build up all the columns from all the CSV files that you need in your aligned output.